# How can I write scientific notation or chemical formula in Android from a regex format?

Tags: java, android, regex

I have some sample data from database and I want to display it on Android.

(C_3H_5N_3O_9)
(4 \times 10^{25}) J

These are the samples from my database.

[image]

[image]
I want to show like this

Which format they used actually?

Answer (score 1):

If your inputs are in the form `C_3H_5N_3O_9) (4 \times 10^{25}) J` where any `_#` is subscript and `^{#}` is superscript you can use the regex below, both will put the number into group 1 of the match.

[`_(\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/ndmXNK/1) for subscript
[`\^{(\d+)}`](https://regex101.com/r/Gkt6Y0/1) for superscript

Comment: Thanks for you ans.
It helped me a lot.
But I think they use a well known format from any Library because there should be many kind of situation for superscript, subscript and math formula.
If you know any library to format this maybe that will helps me better.

Comment: I would look up either Tex or LaTeX. They are different version of the same language for writing documents but they have a very rich text to math formula specification, maybe you can use a derivative or library of them

Answer (score 0):

hey use unicode Superscript and subscript just google the unicode superscript and subscript ..

.what you need is subscript  C3 where 3 is in subscript.

..so go to the page there are unicodes for your text

like \u2045 etc so if you want to make C and 3 in subscript you have to use

TextView t=new TextView;

t.setText("C\u20833");

this is \u2083 for subscript 3 and

C \u2083  3

this is how it works
and so for H and N

H \u2082 2  for H2 and so on..

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts